# How can I prevent swipe to delete from also touching button that is hit incidentally by swipe in Swift?

Tags: swift, button, cell, swipe

I have a Table in Swift whose cells the user can delete by swiping. Unfortunately, there is a button in each cell that, if you swipe and happen to end up swiping near or over the button, it will display the red delete button on the side but then it'll also execute the code connected to the button. How can I prevent the button from being executed if it registers the swipe to delete?

So far, I've tried to make the bounds of the button smaller and I tried different touch events.

Comment: Does the button have a swipe gesture?

Comment: Can you do something like button.isEnabled = false at the beginning of the swipe, and then when the swipe ends you can set that back to true? I am not sure how you have coded your stuff but that should work unless you need the button to do some animation.

Comment: The swipe gesture is built into the action that displays the delete button. But the button doesn't have its own swipe gesture.